# http.NewRequest in golang converting some charterers to % values

Tags: url, go, urlparse

go version go1.8.1 windows/amd64

"net/http" package used to build http request.

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET",`http://domain/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('` + root_folder_url + `')?$expand=Folders,Files`, nil)
```

Here if I print url it shows

```
http://domain/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl%28%27rooturl%27%29?$expand=Folders,Files
```

Not understanding why url parser is replacing `'` to `%27` here.
Whereas I need `'` to be sent as is while requesting.

Comment: It's supposed to do that.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: Why do you think you need it not to do that?

Comment: coz sharepoint wont accept the encoded part ' to %27

Comment: and it is not converting $ signature and , to %

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [http.NewRequest](https://godoc.org/net/http#NewRequest) function calls [url.Parse](https://godoc.org/net/url#Parse) to set the [Request.URL](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.URL). The [URL.RequestURI](https://godoc.org/net/url#URL.RequestURI) method is called to get the request URI written to the network.

An application can override any transformation made by Parse/RequestURI by setting the request URL [Opaque](https://godoc.org/net/url#URL.Opaque) field:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://domain/", nil)
if err != nil {
   // handle error
}
req.URL.Opaque = `/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('` + root_folder_url + `')?$expand=Folders,Files`
```

In this snippet, the argument to NewRequest specifies the protocol and host for the request. The opaque value specifies the request URI written to the network. The request URI does not include host or protocol.

Comment: does opaque appends https to url

Comment: In the above snippet, the argument to NewRequest specifies the protocol and host for the request.  The opaque value specifies the request URI written to the network.  The request URI does not include host or protocol.

Comment: that helps actually